How to correctly delete abandoned Python filelocks on Linux
As mentioned elsewhere, Python's FileLocks do not delete themselves after being released on Linux ([1][2]). This fails:
import os
from filelock import FileLock

with FileLock("/tmp/test.lock"):
    print("Lock acquired")

assert not os.path.exists("/tmp/test.lock")  # Fails

My question, what is the correct way to clean up the lock files? In the official repo, someone suggests to

wrap your locking logic in a context manager at the application/stack level and remove the lock file on exit().

...but doesn't provide code samples. How might someone do this on a multi-process job, like a Pytorch distributed run?

I think there is a race condition in deleting it. Imagine the following sequence: Process 1 and 2 start. 2 acquires the lock file. 1 exits and deletes the file. Process 3 starts, creates a new lock file and acquires it. Now 2 and 3 both hold the lock.

The only solution I see is an additional file for reference counting. This file is only read and modified while the lock is hold. The reference count is incremented when a process may need the lock during its run and is decremented when the process ends (or if it surely doesn't need it anymore). If the refcount reaches zero, refcount file and lock file are deleted while the lock is held yet, then lock is released.

To second what's been discussed in the other thread and other comments here: a lockfile must not be deleted at all after creation on Linux because that may result in a race condition during lock acquisition by the third process as explained so very clearly. Since there is no way to co-ordinate acquire/release cycle outside the use of this very file, along with the underlying file system model (where multiple files under the same name can be opened/locked if they were deleted), it can't be deleted.

@metatoaster Your comment is not constructive. My job is littering my system with tens of thousands of lockfiles every time it runs. Saying that those lockfiles must be left littered across thousands of dirs forever is absurd. The job is completed-- there are no more race conditions to worry about and the lockfiles no longer serve a purpose.

Well, you never stated your goal nor did you provide the exact scenario where this will be proven safe. Does your application have an executor that starts all the underlying jobs (where those underlying jobs would rely on lockfiles to function as a mutex)? If so the deletion of those lockfiles can be safely done by that executor process and not by those underlying job processes. Perhaps the executor can create a temporary directory and direct those jobs to create lockfiles there, and then the executor upon its exit will delete that directory, cleaning everything up.

My point is that with your provided code example there is no safe way to achieve what you want on Linux (because this locking is generally done within individual job processes, not the executor where it is safe to delete lockfiles), and any solution purports to do so from within individual jobs are unsafe and may result in unexpected behavior(s) of your program. Without the additional detail there was no way to be "constructive" in the manner you desire, you need to help others to help them be more constructive by providing the necessary details to ensure a good solution be arrived at.
